# How to take element out of Donut Chart when clicked?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I want to remove an element out of a Donout Chart from ApexCharts JavaScript version. What I have is a Chart with multiple elements and when I click a "slice" of the Donout that "slice" expands. I want to change this so when I click that element the chart removes that elements and changes the proportion. My chart looks like this:

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'donut',
                width: '100%',
                height: 400,
                events: {
                  dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {
                    console.log(event);
                    console.log(chartContext);
                    console.log(config);
                  }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Distribution of people',
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                  fontSize: '20px',
                }
            },
            series: data['people'],
            labels: datos['name_people'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                enabledOnSeries: undefined,
                textAnchor: 'middle',
                distributed: false,
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    colors: undefined
                },
                background: {
                    enabled: true,
                    foreColor: '#fff',
                    padding: 4,
                    borderRadius: 2,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#fff',
                    opacity: 0.9,
                    dropShadow: {
                        enabled: false,
                        top: 1,
                        left: 1,
                        blur: 1,
                        color: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.45
                    }
                },
                dropShadow: {
                    enabled: false,
                    top: 1,
                    left: 1,
                    blur: 1,
                    color: '#000',
                    opacity: 0.45
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `Array.prototype.splice` to remove a data point and label.
Than I call `.updateOptions` to update the chart

```
chart: {
    type: 'donut',
    events: {
        dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {
            // remove the data point
            data.splice(config.dataPointIndex,1);
            // remove the label
            labels.splice(config.dataPointIndex,1);
            // we can't use .updateSeries because labels are seperated in piecharts
            chartContext.updateOptions({
                series: data,
                labels: labels
            }, true)
        }
    },
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nvurgaft/pen/qBjGbrL) that demonstrates this